# mvc download file outside the app folder

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, download

im trying to get a file outside of my application folder to download...

```
public FilePathResult DownloadFile(Guid id, string dateiname)
    {
        string pfad = @"D:\wwwroot\portal_Daten\";

        return File(pfad + dateiname, "application/pdf", dateiname);
    }
```

Errormessage: is a D:\wwwroot\portal_Daten\8/0/6/a/e/974-aaca-426c-b7fc-e6af6c0fb52e/oeffentlich is a physical path, but it was a virtual path expected.

Why can't this work with a physical path? How can i make this to a virtual path?

Regards,
float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have handled this in the path is to use a custom file download http handler (for an asp.net webforms application) and you could use the same here. You could even construct a new sub-class of ActionResult which might net you the same result.

The way I did this was to create an implementation of IHttpHandler, handle the request and return the file. This way you're not restricted to using virtual paths and, as long as your web server security configuration allows, you will be able to access any file on your system and return that to the browser.

Something like:

```
public class MyFileHandler : IHttpHandler
{
  public bool IsReusable
  {
    get { return true; }
  }

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    string filePath = Path.Combine(@"d:\wwwroot\portal_daten", context.Request.QueryString["dateiname"]);

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
  }
}
```

A stripped down example with no checking, but that's for you to fill in. Then register the handler in your web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="MyFileHandler" path="file.axd" type="MvcApplication4.Models.MyFileHandler" verb="GET" />
</handlers>
```

You will of course have to rename classes/namespaces to suit yourself. The actual web link to the file then becomes:

```
http://[domain]/file.axd?dateiname=mypdf.pdf
```

Where [domain] is your domain name/localhost or whatever you're using.

Comment: Hello, i will try it today. I don't wan't to give anyone access to the files on my webserver. An other question: to use virtual paths the folder with data should be in my application folder, or?

Comment: Yes if the file is within your website file structure you can use virtual paths as normal. About my example though, I think you misunderstand; I meant YOU as the programmer will have access to all your files, not just any site user. This way you can just use simple urls and will get around your problem with virtual paths.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Server.MapPath and give it a file location so that it can map the path to a relative directory on the server

so something like

```
public FilePathResult DownloadFile(Guid id, string dateiname)
{
    string pfad = Server.MapPath(@"D:\wwwroot\portal_Daten\");

    var filePath = Path.Combine(pfad, dateiname);
    return File(filePath , "application/pdf", dateiname);
}
```

should work

Comment: requires System.Web referenced

Comment: I have updated the code - the path isn't actually correct as - try it now and see - have you debugged - what is the value of pfad?

Comment: What you've provided in the example is still an absolute path to a folder. Server.MapPath() requires a virtual path (as you've said) which usually starts with a tilde. "~/app_data" for example.

Comment: The path looks like "D:\wwwroot\portal_Daten\" and the error message is the same. i don't know how to debug a website on the webserver.

Comment: @elkdanger you are 100% correct - its not a virtual path so therefore it will never create the correct location